# Putting password on the database (the file mdf)?

Tags: windows

I asked for a password on the database tables can not let anyone see? I would try the following tables show the password .....

If you restore a backup and I got back tables show only the ones that are password ...

I want to let the banks and not on your own password SQL.

Thanks ...

Comment: Are you talking about a **SQL Server** database file? This is **not** Access - you **cannot** just *add a password* to the `.mdf` file - SQL Server security works differently

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you tell me what to do ....؟؟

Comment: SQL Server is a **server-based** solution (not file-based) - you need to have a **login** to that server, and then that login must have a **user** with permissions in each database to do anything. If you want to prevent someone from reading your database - just don't provide a user for a given database.

Comment: In other words, I can not prevent others from accessing tables?

Comment: Yes you can - just don't give those "others" a user for your database! But you **cannot** prevent an admin-level user from attaching the `.mdf` to a SQL Server and then doing whatever he likes to do with it....

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to do it step by step؟

Comment: That's **waaaaay too broad** to explain in a few steps - start by reading [Overview of SQL Server Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669078%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN and then go from there.